# What's the purpose of touchAnchorSide in MotionLayout?

Tags: android, swipe, android-motionlayout

I don't understand what is the purpose of touchAnchorSide in MotionLayout.

I have this path and it works fine with this code:

```
<OnSwipe motion:touchAnchorId="@id/view" motion:dragDirection="dragRight"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty late with the answer, but think it can be helpfull for somebody here.
So `motion:touchAnchorSide` starts animation when your finger cross selected side of the view
For example

```
motion:touchAnchorSide="top"
<!--animation starts working when touch X > view.x-->

motion:touchAnchorSide="bottom"
<!--animation starts working when touch X > (view.x + view.height)-->

motion:touchAnchorSide="left"
<!--animation starts working when touch Y > view.y-->

motion:touchAnchorSide="right"
<!--animation starts working when touch & > (view.y + view.width)-->
```

Look at the picture to understand side positions, brown line is a `touchAnchorSide` where animation starts.

[image]

Also you can replace `motion:touchAnchorSide` and `motion:touchAnchorId` with single `motion:touchRegionId` which need view id and track all sides at the same time.